# failed to list *v1.Pod: pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:monitoring" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope

Tags: kubernetes, open-telemetry

Not sure what I am missing. Please, find below all the config scripts I have used

```
2022-07-21T07:26:56.903Z    info    service/collector.go:220    Starting otelcol... {"service": "my-prom-instance", "Version": "0.54.0", "NumCPU": 4}
2022-07-21T07:26:56.903Z    info    service/collector.go:128    Everything is ready. Begin running and processing data. {"service": "my-prom-instance"}
2022-07-21T07:26:56.902Z    debug   discovery/manager.go:309    Discoverer channel closed   {"service": "my-prom-instance", "kind": "receiver", "name": "prometheus", "pipeline": "metrics", "provider": "static/0"}
W0721 07:26:56.964183       1 reflector.go:324] k8s.io/client-go@v0.24.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: failed to list *v1.Pod: pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:monitoring:otel-collector-collector" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E0721 07:26:56.964871       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go@v0.24.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: Failed to watch *v1.Pod: failed to list *v1.Pod: pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:monitoring:otel-collector-collector" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope
W0721 07:26:58.435237       1 reflector.go:324] k8s.io/client-go@v0.24.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: failed to list *v1.Pod: pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:monitoring:otel-collector-collector" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E0721 07:26:58.435924       1 reflector.go:138]
```

clusterRole.yaml

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: prometheus
  namespace: monitoring
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
  - nodes
  - nodes/proxy
  - services
  - endpoints
  - pods
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  resources:
  - ingresses
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
- nonResourceURLs: ["/metrics"]
  verbs: ["get"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: prometheus
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: prometheus
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: monitoring
```

config-map.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: prometheus-server-conf
  labels:
    name: prometheus-server-conf
  namespace: monitoring
data:
  prometheus.rules: |-
    groups:
    - name: devopscube demo alert
      rules:
      - alert: High Pod Memory
        expr: sum(container_memory_usage_bytes) > 1
        for: 1m
        labels:
          severity: slack
        annotations:
          summary: High Memory Usage
  prometheus.yml: |-
    global:
      scrape_interval: 5s
      evaluation_interval: 5s
    rule_files:
      - /etc/prometheus/prometheus.rules
    alerting:
      alertmanagers:
      - scheme: http
        static_configs:
        - targets:
          - "alertmanager.monitoring.svc:9093"

    scrape_configs:
      - job_name: 'node-exporter'
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
          - role: endpoints
        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoints_name]
          regex: 'node-exporter'
          action: keep
      
      - job_name: 'kubernetes-apiservers'

        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: endpoints
        scheme: https

        tls_config:
          ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace, __meta_kubernetes_service_name, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name]
          action: keep
          regex: default;kubernetes;https

      - job_name: 'kubernetes-nodes'

        scheme: https

        tls_config:
          ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: node

        relabel_configs:
        - action: labelmap
          regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
        - target_label: __address__
          replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
          regex: (.+)
          target_label: __metrics_path__
          replacement: /api/v1/nodes/${1}/proxy/metrics     
      
      - job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'

        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: pod

        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
          action: keep
          regex: true
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
          action: replace
          target_label: __metrics_path__
          regex: (.+)
        - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
          action: replace
          regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
          replacement: $1:$2
          target_label: __address__
        - action: labelmap
          regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
          action: replace
          target_label: kubernetes_namespace
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
          action: replace
          target_label: kubernetes_pod_name
      
      - job_name: 'kube-state-metrics'
        static_configs:
          - targets: ['kube-state-metrics.kube-system.svc.cluster.local:8080']

      - job_name: 'kubernetes-cadvisor'

        scheme: https

        tls_config:
          ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: node

        relabel_configs:
        - action: labelmap
          regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
        - target_label: __address__
          replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
          regex: (.+)
          target_label: __metrics_path__
          replacement: /api/v1/nodes/${1}/proxy/metrics/cadvisor
      
      - job_name: 'kubernetes-service-endpoints'

        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: endpoints

        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
          action: keep
          regex: true
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme]
          action: replace
          target_label: __scheme__
          regex: (https?)
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
          action: replace
          target_label: __metrics_path__
          regex: (.+)
        - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
          action: replace
          target_label: __address__
          regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
          replacement: $1:$2
        - action: labelmap
          regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
          action: replace
          target_label: kubernetes_namespace
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
          action: replace
          target_label: kubernetes_name
```

prometheus-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: prometheus-deployment
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
    app: prometheus-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: prometheus-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: prometheus-server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: prometheus
          image: prom/prometheus
          args:
            - "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
            - "--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus/"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9090
          volumeMounts:
            - name: prometheus-config-volume
              mountPath: /etc/prometheus/
            - name: prometheus-storage-volume
              mountPath: /prometheus/
      volumes:
        - name: prometheus-config-volume
          configMap:
            defaultMode: 420
            name: prometheus-server-conf
  
        - name: prometheus-storage-volume
          emptyDir: {}
```

otel-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: opentelemetry.io/v1alpha1
kind: OpenTelemetryCollector
metadata:
  name: otel-collector
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  config: |
    receivers:
      prometheus:
        config:
          scrape_configs:
            - job_name: 'kube-state-metrics'
              scrape_interval: 5s
              scrape_timeout: 1s
              static_configs:
                - targets: ['kube-state-metrics.kube-system.svc.cluster.local:8080']
            - job_name: k8s
              kubernetes_sd_configs:
              - role: pod
              relabel_configs:
              - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
                regex: "true"
                action: keep
              metric_relabel_configs:
              - source_labels: [__name__]
                regex: "(request_duration_seconds.*|response_duration_seconds.*)"
                action: keep
    processors:
      batch:
    exporters:
      logging:
    service:
      pipelines:
        metrics:
          receivers: [prometheus]
          exporters: [logging]
      telemetry:
        logs:
          level: debug
          initial_fields:
            service: my-prom-instance
```

otel-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: otel-collector-sa
  namespace: monitoring
```

Answer (score 6):

the service account is defined with name otel-collector-sa, and your ClusterRoleBinding link to service account default

Comment: Yeah, I figured out later

Comment: @RiteshSinha if this is the correct answer, and you are no longer looking for an answer, please accept the answer (to avoid having an unanswered question), or delete the question

Comment: i came across similar problem, I was writing controller without CRD, in this case i had to make apiGroup as ""    (empty )